# $A$ is nilpotent matrix and satisfies the equation $A^5=3A^3-2A.$ Prove $A=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

I'm stuck at this question , I had an idea how to solve it but I think it's not good tho.

The Question :

> $A$ is nilpotent and $A^5=3A^3-2A,$ prove $A=0.$
> ( $A^k = 0 :$ for certain  $k\in \mathbb{N}$)

My try : I tried changing the equation to the form $\Rightarrow A=\frac{A^3(3I-A^2)}{2}$ and then multiplying both sides by $A^{k-3}$ and proceed with $\Rightarrow  A^{k-2} = 0$.

But I'm not sure how to proceed with it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** If $A^n=0$ and $n \geq 2$ then, multiply your relation by $A^{n-2}$ to get
$$A^{n+3}=3A^{n+1}-2A^{n-1}$$

Show that $A^{n-1}=0$. Repeat.

**P.S.** If you learned about the minimal polynomial, then the following is a shorter alternate solution: The minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide some $X^n$ and $X^5-3X^3+2X$, and hence it must divide their GCD which is $X$.

Comment: That's what I was wondering with $A^{k-2}$, I though to repeat it and get that the matrix is 0..

Comment: I believe the lhs should be $A^{n+3}$.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Actually we just study Minimal polynomial right now and your second answer makes more sense to me :). like you said , The GCD between both of them is Maximum $X$ , so we have only one option for the minimal polynomial and it's $X$ $\Rightarrow A=0$ by Cayley-Hamiltion

Comment: @Roach87 Just for completeness: if the minimal polynomial is $X$ then $A=0$ by definition of the minimal polynomial. Cayley-Hamilton tells you that $A$ is evaluated to zero by the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach:

$$A(\underbrace{A^4 - 3A^2}_{B:=}+2I)=O$$

Note that $B$ is nilpotent because $A$ is nilpotent.
Hence, the only eigenvalue of $B$ is $ \lambda = 0$. Hence, $B+2I$ is invertible (otherwise $\lambda = -2$ would be an eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix which is a contradiction).

It follows by multiplying by $(B+2I)^{-1}$ from the right that $A =O$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $A$ is nilpotent but $A \neq 0$, then there is some $v \in \Bbb F^n$ such that $A v \neq 0$ but $A^2 v = 0$. Now, multiply both sides of the given equation, $$A^5 = 3 A^3 - 2 A ,$$ by $v$.